# Is there a way to store and display dask distributed history

Tags: dask-distributed

Is there a way to store an display(over Bokeh) dask distributed history
I would like to analyse/compare old dask distributed runs

Comment: What exactly do you mean by history? Logs? Tasks graphs? Profile history?

Comment: @VladyslavMoisieienkov 
Tasks graphs , Profile history

Comment: As I know there is no such functionality. You can submit an issue with the proposal. Link - https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues

Comment: Found in distributed docs `client.profile()` method (https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.profile). You can use it for manually collecting and saving profiling info

Comment: @VladyslavMoisieienkov , thanks mate